# changing the components of layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I am beginner in android and I have a `gridview` of images which when you click on image it will move you to the `SecondActivity`. and in `SecondActivity` I have some information related to each images. the layout of `SecondActivity` is same for all images and I want to change the title, text and the image for each image in the same layout.
I used `setTitle`, `setText` and `setImageDrawable()` but it does not change. I will but some lines of my code, maybe it will be completely wrong so if it was please guide me to a simple source.

**in product class**

```
public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

**in MainActivity**

```
public List<Product> getProductList() {
        //pseudo code to get product, replace your code to get real product here
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.ii1, " Story Name", "This is description 1"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i2, "Story Name", "This is description 2"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i3, "Story Name", "This is description 3"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i4, "Story Name", "This is description 4"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i5, "Story Name", "This is description 5"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i6, "Story Name", "This is description 6"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i8, "Story Name", "This is description 8"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i9, "Story Name", "This is description 9"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i10, "Story Name", "This is description 10"));

        return productList;
    }
```

**in SecondActivity**

```
 mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        img  = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
         t=findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("title"));

            if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.ii1));
                t.setText(bundle.getString("title"));
            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")){
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i2));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i3));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i4));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i5));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i6));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i8));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i9));

            }

            else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Story Name")) {
                img .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.i10));

            }


        }
    }

}
```

**second activity XML**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ii1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />
```

Comment: when i send it it was not completed . sorry my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click one image, go to your click event and hold the position of your image. Then send informations from the list to the SecondActivity.

Comment: you mean that i will pass the information by using intent then putExtra and start the activity

Comment: Yes. That's what i'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

this is working with me now 
I sent the text to the second activity like this

**MainActivity**

```
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    Bundle b= new Bundle();
                    b.putString("Story Name", productList.get(position).getTitle().toString());
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
TextView t =findViewById(R.id.textView4);
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String story=b.getString("Story Name");
t.setText(story);
```

I also use that on Image and title